# Baking a Cake at the Wrong Temperature

Tags: cake

I mistakenly baked my Carrot Cake at 375 degrees for 35 minutes as opposed to the correct temperature of 325 degrees for the same amount of time.  What will happen?  Do I need to throw it away?

Comment: It won't be poison - have you tried a bite?

Comment: Cover it in icing to cover it up.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely to be quite over-baked, probably quite dry and unpleasant on the outside.  It may also develop an unpleasant scorched flavor, especially on the outside.

It will not be unsafe, however.